# Leaflet openstreetmap loads, but does not appear

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openstreetmap

I try to make a leaflet map and added Openstreetmap as a background map. But if I load the map, nothing appears. Checking the firefox network analysis all the required tiles are loaded succesfully, but they do not show.

### My HTML code :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==" crossorigin=""></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map">
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
        <!--- a logo will appear here --->
    </div>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
</body>
```

### My javascript code :

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [51.505, -0.09],
    zoom: 13
});

var osm = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
});
osm.addTo(map);
```

The div "map" has a higher z-index than "logo", so that should not be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is `map style` ?

You should give a height and a width to your map in order to be rendered

```
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SWhax9M6uYX0x9yb0S0f?p=preview)

Comment: I used "#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}" in the .css file, but that does not seem to work, since your code fixes it. Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: `height: 100%` makes no sense in this case as percentage refers to the parent DOM element. `100%` of the style that the parent dom element has been assigned. In your case there is no parent element for the `<div id="map">` with predefined style and height in that case. Therefore you need to use specific px size. Please accept and or up-vote the answer if it helped you.